# removing stop words from a specific string using c#

Tags: c#

I have an array of words and I want to remove them from an input string, could anyone tell me what is the better way to conduct this task?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting errors? Do you have some code you can show? Please give examples of your array of words and your input string (how it starts) and what it should look like at the end.

Comment: How big is your dataset that you need *the fastest way* to do it?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show what you've tried so far and what specific problems you're having.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
string[] arrToCheck = new string[] { "try ", "yourself", "before " };

string input = "Did you try this yourself before asking";
foreach (string word in arrToCheck )
{
   input = input.Replace(word, "");
}
MessageBox.Show("result is "+input);
```

input variable will now have a string which does not have those words in your array.

Comment: actually, I have more than way to conduct this task. but I want to know which is the fastest way. because my dataset is to big.

Comment: What will happen with the string "Did you try this yourself before asking, Try this yourself"